# add an array to json object with PhP

Tags: php, json

I want to encode an array of answers to a question when retrieving that question from the database.

**Desired Result:**

```
[{"question":"What Barks","answers":["Cats","Dogs","Birds","Elephants"],"correct":1}]
```

**Source Code**

```
require_once("connect.php");
$sql = "SELECT questions.question, GROUP_CONCAT(answers.answer) answers, questions.correct FROM questions,answers  where answers.questionID = questions.questionID group by questions.question";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $data = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
}

echo json_encode($data);

mysqli_close($conn);
```

**Current Result:**

```
[{"question":"What Barks?","answers":"Cat,Dog,Fish,Cow","correct":"1"}]
```

Comment: Try to chnage From $sql = "SELECT questions.question, questions.correct, answers.answer FROM questions INNER JOIN answers ON answers.questionID = questions.questionID";    TO $sql = "SELECT questions.question, questions.correct, answers.answer As answersFROM questions INNER JOIN answers ON answers.questionID = questions.questionID";

Comment: You will need to format the array to suit your desired result. Right now you are just encoding the DB result.

Comment: I think your DB schema needs some work!  Your data isn't even 1NF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is sample solution, based on example in your question:

```
require_once("connect.php");
$sql = 
    "SELECT questions.question, GROUP_CONCAT(answers.answer) answers, questions.correct FROM questions, answers WHERE answers.questionID = questions.questionID GROUP BY questions.question";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $data = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $a = array(
            "question"=>$row["question"],
            "answers"=>explode(",", $row["answers"]),
            "correct"=>$row["correct"]
        );
        $data[] = $a;
    }
}
echo json_encode($data);
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the mysql query as follows:

```
> SELECT questions.question, 
> questions.correct,GROUP_CONCAT(answers.answer) answers FROM
> questions,answers  where answers.questionID = questions.questionID
> group by questions.question
```

> Here we use a GROUP_CONCAT aggregate function from MySQL

.

Comment: Thanks for reply, almost works as intended currently the  result is producing [{"question":"What Barks?","answers":"Cat,Dog,Fish,Cow","correct":"1"}] How do I add it in to an array

Comment: Can you try this @Bradley
`if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $data = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $answers = $row["answers"];
  $row["answers"] = explode(',', $answers);
        $data[] = $row;
  
    }
}`